# OpenSSL ASN1_item_ex_d2i memory leak

Tags: c, sockets, ssl, memory-leaks, openssl

I have a probem with openSSL lib, I have memory leak :

```
==9904== 
==9904== HEAP SUMMARY:
==9904==     in use at exit: 163,350 bytes in 2,867 blocks
==9904==   total heap usage: 5,104 allocs, 2,237 frees, 1,162,949 bytes allocated
==9904== 
==9904== 4,808 (184 direct, 4,624 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 279 of 284
==9904==    at 0x4C28BED: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:263)
==9904==    by 0x5106DFF: CRYPTO_malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
==9904==    by 0x51A27EB: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
==9904==    by 0x51A517F: ASN1_item_ex_d2i (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
==9904==    by 0x51A5BF3: ASN1_item_d2i (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
==9904==    by 0x4E4789C: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0)
==9904==    by 0x4E48ED7: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0)
==9904==    by 0x4026BD: main (main.c:68)
==9904== 
==9904== LEAK SUMMARY:
==9904==    definitely lost: 184 bytes in 1 blocks
==9904==    indirectly lost: 4,624 bytes in 103 blocks
==9904==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9904==    still reachable: 158,542 bytes in 2,763 blocks
==9904==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9904== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==9904== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes
==9904== 
==9904== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==9904== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 8 from 6)
```

Do you know this problem ? Can you help me please ?

Romain
Supvize

Comment: Have you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11759725/opensslssl-library-init-memory-leak ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to recompile the libssl.so.1.0.0 library with debug option (ie ./config -d ...) to be able to trace the memory leak source

Answer (score 0):

I just investigated a similar leak report and it turns out that a call to `X509_free()` was missing after the call to `SSL_get_peer_certificate()`.

The relevant part of OpenSSL docs is:

> SSL_get_peer_certificate() returns a pointer to the X509 certificate the peer presented. If the peer did not present a certificate, NULL is returned.
>
> ...
>
> The reference count of the X509 object is incremented by one, so that it will not be destroyed when the session containing the peer certificate is freed. The X509 object must be explicitly freed using X509_free().