# Where (if) do I clean up the BIO returned by BIO_new_socket?

Tags: c++, openssl

I use openSSL to implement a secure server but I am struggling somewhat with the documentation.

For each connection that is made to the server I:

- create the SSL:  `mp_ssl = SSL_new(...)`
- create a BIO: `BIO* lp_bio = BIO_new_socket(..., BIO_NOCLOSE);`
- set the BIO: `SSL_set_bio(mp_ssl, lp_bio, lp_bio);`
- accept: `SSL_accept(mp_ssl);`

When the connection is terminated

- cleanup: `SSL_free(mp_ssl);`

Now this all works OK, but I have a memory leak somewhere. I wonder if anyone can explain to me if and/or when I need to clean up that BIO* myself, or is this perhaps done when I do `SSL_free(...)` ?

FWIW - I Create the SSL* in the (main) thread after its done the TCP/IP accept, but the BIO and SSL_Accept are done using a worker thread (I had some timing issues where setting up the SSL handshake was blocking my main thread for too long)

Comment: How do you know that you have a memory leak?

Comment: `SSL_free` also frees the assigned BIO. So for each `SSL_new` in your program execution path (whatever it may be) you have to free it with `SSL_free` and for each `CTX_new` you have to free it with `CTX_free`. Also, it is important to setup multithreading for OpenSSL, as it doesn't work _out of the box_

Comment: Ok thanks. I do indeed setup multithreading by providing the callback functions `CRYPTO_set_id_callback(id_function)` and `CRYPTO_set_locking_callback(locking_function)`. I am only using one CTX (which I hold in the listener) to create each connection SSL - I hope that is an OK assumption.

Comment: Also see [How to properly uninitialize OpenSSL](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29845527) and [OpenSSL::SSL_library_init() memory leak](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11759725).